# Unable To Communicate with UCI through Java Program

Tags: stockfish, uci

I am writing a java program to connect to the Stockfish Engine and get the best move for some FENs.
My Connection code is :

```
public class connector {
    private Process engineProcess;
    private BufferedReader processReader;
    private OutputStreamWriter processWriter;
    private static final String Path = "path\to\stockfish.exe";
    
    public boolean startEngine() {
        try {
            engineProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Path);
            processReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    engineProcess.getInputStream()));
            processWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    engineProcess.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public void sendCommand(String command) {
        try {
            processWriter.write(command + "\n");
            processWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public String getBestMove(String fen, int waitTime) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
        sendCommand("position fen " + fen);
        sendCommand("go movetime " + waitTime);
        return getOutput(waitTime + 20).split("bestmove ")[1].split(" ")[0];
    }

    public String getOutput(int waitTime) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(waitTime); 
            sendCommand("isready"); 
            while (true) { 
           String text = processReader.readLine(); 
           System.out.println("Text is " + text); 
           if(text.equals("readyok"))
              break; 
           else 
              buffer.append(text + "\n"); 
              
          }
          catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
         
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    public void stopEngine() {
        try {
            sendCommand("quit");
            processReader.close();
            processWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    
}
```

My Driver Code is as Follows :

```
connector con = new connector();
        boolean started = con.startEngine();
        if(started) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            String bestMove = con.getBestMove("1nbqkbnr/1ppppppp/p7/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1", 5000);
            
            System.out.println(bestMove);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Failed To Start Engine");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

The Output I am getting is :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
at connectors.connector.getBestMove(connector.java:42)
```

I am having a hard time understanding what is wrong with my code. I understand that using processReader , I am reading the InputStream of the engine and appending it to String "text" until I encounter "readyok" , and finally returning this string. But when I output this , it gives me everything including info like

`info depth 1 seldepth 1 multipv 1 score cp 539 nodes 83 nps 41500 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e5f6 info depth 2 seldepth 2 multipv 1 score cp 790 nodes 182 nps 91000 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e4d5 b7b6 e5f6`

I am unable to get the Best Move. How can I do this?

Comment: this question needs to be asked on stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`info depth 1 seldepth 1 multipv 1 score cp 539 nodes 83 nps 41500 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e5f6 info depth 2 seldepth 2 multipv 1 score cp 790 nodes 182 nps 91000 tbhits 0 time 2 pv e4d5 b7b6 e5f6`

obviously doesn't have any best move in it. Stockfish needs time to give you a move. Your program will need to filter out those principal variation lines.

Please don't use `waitTime`.  Did you ask for 20 seconds? Chess engine may not stop the search exactly after 20s. Do something like this:

- Wait from Stockfish in real-time. In C++, it's something like `read()` (can't remember exactly without a Google search). Your worker thread waits for the next Stockfish output.
- Check if "bestmove" is in the line, if not, do nothing

Pseudocode looks like:

```
f = ... // handler to Stockfish's standard output
while (true) {
    line = f.read() // Read Stockfish's next line. Blocked if nothing.
    if ("bestmove" in line) { // Best move?
        ... parse the move ...
    } else {
        print("Do nothing!")
    }
}
```